# Problems in Kotlin with Jackson method readValue and HashMap

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I try to translate this function in Java that use Jackson ObjectMapper:

```
public static HashMap<String, Serializable> jsonDecode(String body) {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, HashMap.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

To Kotlin (this code is proposed by IntelliJ IDEA):

```
fun jsonDecode(body: String?): java.util.HashMap<String, Serializable>? {
    return try {
        ObjectMapper().readValue(body, HashMap::class.java)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        null
    }
}
```

But the compiler throws an error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is HashMap<*, *>! but HashMap<String,
> Serializable>? was expected

Answer (score 1):

I try with this:

```
fun jsonDecode(body: String): java.util.HashMap<String, Serializable>? {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
    val result: java.util.HashMap<String, Serializable> = mapper.readValue(body)
    return try {
        result
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! A suggestion for improvement: just like the original Java code, this function creates a new ObjectMapper for every call. It's much less expensive to create just one instance and reuse it. This could be done by declaring `mapper` outside the function.

Comment: note this uses a kotlin extension method on object mapper which eventually delegates to a call on the objectMapper thats similar to the java code but uses a TypeReference instead of a Class https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html